# How to call the stock Grid (Interpolation) tool without specifying an algorithm in QGIS Python console?

Tags: pyqgis

Question says it all. Looking to use the Raster > Analysis > Grid (Interpolation) tool in a python workflow, but need to be able to run it with the default of no specified algorithm. I can only find GDAL/OGR interpolation methods that already specify the algorithm in the processing toolbox.

Comment: You may need to directly call [gdal_grid](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) since the option to not specify an algorithm is not available in the Processing toolbox.

Comment: @Joseph Where would I find documentation on which parameters to use (other than the gdal_grid instructions for use in the command line)? I'm assuming processing.runalg("qgis:analysis:gdal_grid", [input points],[interpolation field],[output raster]) isn't enough?

Comment: Don't think that's possible to do as the processing plugin only lists those 4 tools. My guess would be you would need to call gdal_grid directly but I haven't used this. [Here is a list of available gdal analysis tools](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis.html#gdal-analysis).

Comment: @Joseph Looking for other means of achieving the same results. Do you have any experience with calling plugins from processing scripts? Would be interested in using the "Raster Interpolation" plugin instead, as it seems to be giving me expected results

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not. There are a number of other posts in calling that very same plugin from the python console. See [How to call the interpolation plugin from the python console?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103506/how-to-call-the-interpolation-plugin-from-the-python-console) and the linked posts.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway. I think I'm going to use the SAGA IDW Interpolation tool from the processing toolbox. Makes life easier, and I'm starting to get similar results as from the gdal_grid.

Comment: Most welcome and nice one, hope you get the results you're looking for ;)