# PyQGIS raster interpolation from vector layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I want to generate raster from line vector layer using PyQGIS. I was following this post:
[How to call the interpolation plugin from the python console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103506/how-to-call-the-interpolation-plugin-from-the-python-console/236856#236856)

but I have a problem with:

```
layer_data.InterpolationAttribute =0
```

It works, but when I try to set different index it still takes values from first column. It looks like 0 index is default and can't be modified. I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.

Maybe this is a reason?

Comment: Hi, there is a probably a bug. I have the same problem so I automatically delete all columns before interpolation.