# How to automate the QGIS Raster Interpolation Plugin using python console?

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted

I have a rainfall data from 1961 to 2015 for each day of this years. I need to create a raster for each day with this configuration.
[image]

Do you know how to automate this using this plugin and python?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @R.G.! I think this is a duplicate question of this: [How to call the interpolation plugin from the python console?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103506/how-to-call-the-interpolation-plugin-from-the-python-console)

Comment: I couldn't solve my problem with this other question!

Comment: What's not working for you?

Comment: the way to automate the raster creation with interpolation plugin for a everyday raster with the configurations above.
I have not a number values to, i was trying to automate it with gdal grid using IDW too, but i can't make it wok with nan values and at the end the interpolation with nan values and with the nan values removed are different from each other. What should i do to create this rasters automatically and not manually?

Comment: I could solve my problem with gdal grid interpolation, i automated it using linux terminal, because on grid interpolation it gives all the comands i need to interpolate it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to provide a solution to your problem in another answer of the following existing question:

**[How to compute an interpolation raster from the python console in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/233322/33338)**

This solution is based on the usage of the QGIS interpolation classes (`QgsInterpolator`, `QgsTINInterpolator`, `QgsIDWInterpolator`, `QgsGridFileWriter`) in a short python script. I hope it poses an easy solution for you!